# Nested attributes and belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

Rails 4.2.8

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :rememberable,
         :validatable, :encryptable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:facebook], encryptor: :restful_authentication_sha1
   attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :is_admin, :is_master

   has_one :customer
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
end
```

**customer.rb**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

**customers_contoller.rb**

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @customer = current_user.customer
  end

  def update
    @customer = current_user.customer
    @customer.update customer_params
    render 'edit'
  end

  private

  def customer_params
    params.require(:customer).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :phone, user_attributes: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
  end
end
```

**customers/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @customer, html: { class: 'checkout-attributes profile-form' } do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <span class="help-block">First Name</span>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <span class="help-block">Last Name</span>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <span class="help-block">Email</span>
      <%= fields_for :user, @customer.user do |u| %>
      <%= u.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <span class="help-block">Phone Number</span>
      <%= f.text_field :phone, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <span class="help-block">Password</span>
      <%= fields_for :user, @customer.user do |u| %>
      <%= u.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <span class="help-block">Confirm Password</span>
      <%= fields_for :user, @customer.user do |u| %>
      <%= u.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
      <% end %>                      
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

That's what I see in log

```
Started PATCH "/customers/560738" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-04 08:15:20-0500 Processing by CustomersController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OL7NCIMKCb+LQZ+1voahUsNyD37q6sal8W7HsV4EKKP9ABMuDVGqxs0nFS2Cyo7A6XBkRLYv9tjTYH4kaHNdkA==", "image"=>"", "customer"=>{"first_name"=>"Jack", "last_name"=>"Drobazko", "phone"=>"5084427293"}, "user"=>{"email"=>"ddd@fff.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "id"=>"560738"}
```

Also I see that **customer_params** methods gives filtered (without user part) hash **{"first_name"=>"Jack", "last_name"=>"Drobazko", "phone"=>"5084427293"}**

So how to make it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your log file:

> "image"=>"", "customer"=>{"first_name"=>"Jack",
>   "last_name"=>"Drobazko", "phone"=>"5084427293"},
>   **"user"=>{"email"=>"ddd@fff.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "password_confirmation"=>" ...**

All your [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) inputs outside of a main form. Fix your form to wrap all user input in the [`fields_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) helper.

<sub>Note about `f.fields_for` and simple `fields_for`, **it's very important**</sub>

```
<%= form_for @customer, html: { class: 'checkout-attributes profile-form' } do |f| %>   
  # some code here  
      <%= f.fields_for :user, @customer.user do |u| %>
        <%= u.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= u.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
        <%= u.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  # some code here
```

Here is wonderful article from Rails core team, about using [`nested attributes`](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/1/26/nested-model-forms/).